# knockout form validation message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I'd like to use Knockout.js to highlight errors on a form.

Currently i see all errors when i get the form, 
I want to get them only if the user press on Save button. 
So I'm try to set a flag that will be true only if the user press on it, and then to use it in all form but i don't have success with that.
I will apreciate some help with that. (or any other way to do it)
so i will need someting like that on my html:

```
<div class='liveExample' data-bind="css: {hideErrors: !hasBeenSubmittedOnce()">
```

and somewhere in my js file:

```
        this.hasBeenSubmittedOnce = ko.observable(false);

    this.save = function(){
        this.hasBeenSubmittedOnce(true);
    }
```

that my files

HTML

```
<div class='liveExample' data-bind="css: {hideErrors: !hasBeenSubmittedOnce()">
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Store:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3" data-bind="css: { error: storeName.hasError() }">
            <input data-bind='value: storeName, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
            <span data-bind='text: storeName.validationMessage'> </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Company ID:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3" data-bind="css: { error: companyId.hasError }">
            <input data-bind='value: companyId, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
            <span data-bind='text: companyId.validationMessage'> </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3" data-bind="css: { error: address.hasError }">
            <input data-bind='value: address, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
            <span data-bind='text: address.validationMessage'> </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Phone:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3" data-bind="css: { error: phone.hasError }">
            <input data-bind='value: phone, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
            <span data-bind='text: phone.validationMessage'> </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-4">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: save">Add store</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Store:
            
                
                 
            
        
        
            Company ID:
            
                
                 
            
        
        
            Address
            
                
                 
            
        
        
            Phone:
            
                
                 
            
        
        
            
                Add store

```
</form>
```

js

```
define(['knockout'], function (ko){

ko.extenders.required = function(target, overrideMessage) {
    //add some sub-observables to our observable
    target.hasError = ko.observable();
    target.validationMessage = ko.observable();

    //define a function to do validation
    function validate(newValue) {
        target.hasError(newValue ? false : true);
        target.validationMessage(newValue ? "" : overrideMessage || "This field is required");
    }
    validate(target());
    target.subscribe(validate);
    return target;
};

function AppViewModel(storeName, companyId, address, phone) {

    this.storeName = ko.observable(storeName).extend({  required:"" });
    this.companyId = ko.observable(companyId).extend({ required: "" });
    this.address = ko.observable(address).extend({ required: "" });
    this.phone = ko.observable(phone).extend({ required: ""});


    this.hasError = ko.computed(function(){
        return this.storeName.hasError() || this.companyId.hasError();
    }, this);


    this.hasBeenSubmittedOnce = ko.observable(false);

    this.save = function(){
        this.hasBeenSubmittedOnce(true);
    }

}

return AppViewModel;
});
```

CSS file

```
    .form-group span {
    display: inherit;
}

.hideErrors .error span {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did some work around for this and not sure it is better way or not.

```
var showError=ko.observableArray([]);//it will store show Error Message
 ko.extenders.required = function(target, overrideMessage) {
 //add some sub-observables to our observable
 target.hasError = ko.observable();
 target.validationMessage = ko.observable();

 //define a function to do validation
 function validate(newValue) {
    target.hasError($.trim(newValue) ? false : true);
    target.validationMessage($.trim(newValue) ? "" : overrideMessage || "This field is required");

 }
 showError.push(function(){validate(target());});
 target.subscribe(validate);
 return target;
};

function AppViewModel(storeName, companyId, address, phone) {
 this.storeName = ko.observable(storeName).extend({  required:"" });
 this.companyId = ko.observable(companyId).extend({ required: "xcxcx" });
 this.address = ko.observable(address).extend({ required: "" });
 this.phone = ko.observable(phone).extend({ required: ""});


 this.hasError = ko.computed(function(){
    return self.storeName.hasError() || self.companyId.hasError();
 }, this);


 this.hasBeenSubmittedOnce = ko.observable(false);

 this.save = function(){
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(showError(),function(func){
       func();
    });
 }

}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BDL8B/5/)

Comment: Not sure to if it's better, but it really work :) now I'm trying to combine knockout-validation.js with that :)

Comment: I am also not sure but i think ko validation js is better to use instead of writing extender yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the visible knockout binding:

```
<div data-bind="visible: hasBeenSubmittedOnce">
```

As for the error class, you can use the define the default knockout validation class: 'validationElement' and call

```
 ko.validation.init({ decorateElement: true});
```

Here you can find more:
https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Configuration
(please note that decorateElement has been [renamed 2013-11-21](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/commit/5fe4a5aa1aa86878fe46bef25ef2e0a37d449d44) to 'decorateInputElement')

Comment: @Lorenz_i I edited my answer, please take a look as you don't have to handle the css error class for each of your elements.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still struggle with the validatoin.js. i don't get anything working with it

Comment: Sure you can. i did it now with the js file, want it?

Comment: You did not add the knockout validation reference. You can use the following cdn: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-validation/1.0.2/knockout.validation.min.js You can as well check the fiddle, i added this link as external reference http://jsfiddle.net/EpLtu/2/